# How to sort array by matching the closest to input string?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the array by having the values which are the closest matches first in array.

What I have so far:

```
$array = array("Year 6", "Year 4", "Eden camp trip", "Easter school", "Eden camp trip", "Year 6 Chester Zoo", "Year 6 Trip to Chester");

$search = strtolower("Year 6");

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($search) {
    similar_text($search, $a, $aa);
    similar_text($search, $b, $bb);
    return $aa === $bb ? 0 : ($aa > $bb ? -1 : 1);
});

echo "<pre>";
     print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Year 6
    [1] => Year 4
    [2] => Year 6 Chester Zoo
    [3] => Year 6 Trip to Chester
    [4] => Easter school
    [5] => Eden camp trip
    [6] => Eden camp trip
)
```

expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Year 6
    [1] => Year 6 Chester Zoo
    [2] => Year 6 Trip to Chester
    [3] => Year 4 
    [4] => Easter school
    [5] => Eden camp trip
    [6] => Eden camp trip
)
```

Comment: Unless your expectation of *closest match* is covered by built-in functions like  `similar_text`, `levenshtein`, or `soundex`, you need to implement string comparison yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay taking [@AlexBlex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110423/alex-blex) advice..I went and researched and found the following way of doing what I was looking for.

```
$array = array("Year 6", "Year 4", "Eden camp trip", "Easter school", "Eden camp trip", "Year 6 Chester Zoo", "Year 6 Trip to Chester");

$search = strtolower("Year 6");

usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($search) {

        $a = strtolower($a);
        $b = strtolower($b);

        if ($a == $search) return -1;
        if ($b == $search) return 1;

        $x = strpos($a, $search);
        $y = strpos($b, $search);

        if ($x !== false && $y === false) return -1;
        if ($y !== false && $x === false) return 1;
        if ($x !== false && $y !== false) { 

            if ($x != $y)  return $x > $y ? 1 : -1;

            $al = strlen($a);
            $bl = strlen($b);

            if ($al != $bl)  return $al > $bl ? 1 : -1;

            return 0;
        }

        $ac = levenshtein($search, $a);
        $bc = levenshtein($search, $b);

        if ($ac != $bc) return $ac > $bc ? 1 : -1;

        return 0;
 });

    echo "<pre>";
         print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Year 6
    [1] => Year 6 Chester Zoo
    [2] => Year 6 Trip to Chester
    [3] => Year 4
    [4] => Easter school
    [5] => Eden camp trip
    [6] => Eden camp trip
)
```